# How to correctly bind function with arguments in component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been using React for a few months now, and one of the things I'm finding most difficult is how to properly bind functions that take arguments.

Currently, I have three inputs that share a single update function, but require a different first argument to be passed. Here is my component:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    const { onChange } = this.props;
    return(
      <div className='my_component'>
        <Row>
          <Column>
            <Input 
              value={item1} 
              onChange={ (newValue) => onChange('item1', newValue) } />
          </Column>
        </Row>
        <Row>
          <Column>
            <Input 
              value={item2} 
              onChange={ (newValue) => onChange('item2', newValue) } />
          </Column>
        </Row>
        <Row>
          <Column>
            <Input 
              value={item3} 
              onChange={ (newValue) => onChange('item3', newValue) } />
          </Column>
        </Row>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

So, currently, I'm using arrow functions in my render function of the component. But through research, I've found that obviously has performance issue in terms of re-rendering.

The solution offered is to bind in the constructor using

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
}

handleChange(event) {
  this.props.onChange('ARGUMENT REQUIRED!', event.target.value);
}
```

The problem is, that I cannot get that first argument to work... Am I supposed to create a function for each and bind one for each in the constructor, like so:

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.handleItem1Change= this.handleItem1Change.bind(this)
  this.handleItem2Change= this.handleItem2Change.bind(this)
  this.handleItem3Change= this.handleItem3Change.bind(this)
}

handleItem1Change(newValue) {
    this.props.onChange('item1', newValue);
}
handleItem2Change(event) {
    this.props.onChange('item2', newValue);
}
handleItem3Change(event) {
    this.props.onChange('item3', newValue);
}
```

That seems repetitive...is there a more streamlined way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried:
onChange={ (newValue) => onChange.bind(this, 'item1') } />

Comment: Yes and store this 'item1' in some kind of refs for the input element. So when u call: onChange={ (newValue) => onChange(this, this.refs) }... just check once for using the strings in ref.

Comment: @bergi The `newValue` is passed from the input callback, and I messed up the `event.target.value` that is was is passed up, so it is just the new value. That is relatively irrelevant to the problem at hand, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have control of the `Input` component, why not have a prop such as `name` and then in the `Input` component pass in the `onChange` function as a prop.

In the `Input` component whereever you are handling the change you could just do.

```
<Input 
 value={item3} 
 onChange={ onChange } 
 name='item3'

/>

// in the Input component
handleChange = (value) => {
  this.props.onChange(value, this.props.name)
}
```

and then you would just need to update your `onChange` to put the value first and the name second. Reason for doing it that way is to ensure this doesn't break your `Input` component in the other places that it is used since `value` will still be the first argument, and `name` is a secondary optional argument.

if you are passing the event back in the `onChange` instead of value you can still use the event and just do `e.target.name` as long as you are applying the `name` prop to the input thats rendered in `Input` and would look like:

```
handleChange(event) {
  this.props.onChange(event.target.name, event.target.value);
}
```

Comment: I like this a lot. This definitely works. I originally didn't have a name prop, but I probably should have anyway!

Comment: What I have found is that anytime you are needing to reuse a function and don't want to bind the arguments, then you just need to have a component that can be delegated as the provider of said argument based on its props.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass arguments that you want to partially apply right into [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.handleItem1Change = this.props.onChange.bind(this, 'item1');
  this.handleItem2Change = this.props.onChange.bind(this, 'item2');
  this.handleItem3Change = this.props.onChange.bind(this, 'item3');
}
```

Alternatively, you can still use arrow functions there:

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.handleItem1Change = newValue => this.props.onChange('item1', newValue);
  this.handleItem2Change = newValue => this.props.onChange('item2', newValue);
  this.handleItem3Change = newValue => this.props.onChange('item3', newValue);
}
```

Comment: Right, but that's essentially the same as my second solution. It definitely works, but is relatively repetitive. Was hoping there might be a way to do it with a single bound function instead of declaring a new binding for each.

Comment: @TomNolan Of course you can do that in a loop or whatever, but for only three items that might not save a lot

Comment: Btw, I guess the most idiomatic React way would be to let the `Row` (or `Column` or `Input`) component handle all this, so that you don't have to repeat it in `MyComponent`

Answer (score 0):

Just add a new layer of abstraction, something like this::

```
form.js //use the component RowInput
<RowInput name={'item1'} value={'item'} onChange={onChange} />

RowInput.js // stupid/dumb component
export const RowInput = (name, item, onChange)=>
          <Column>
            <Input 
              value={item} 
              onChange={ (val) => onChange(name) } />
          </Column>
```

Answer (score -1):

you could try this to bind the on change callback

```
<Input value={item1} onChange={onChange.bind(null,'item1') } />
```

the callback will look like this

```
onChange(item, event)
```

Comment: This will cause the same issue that the OP is trying to solve which is not binding the function in the render method which will cause unnecessary rerenders on the component